# When running npx json-server --watch Data/db.json --port 8000, it throws a new error

Tags: json-server

Whenever I am running `npx json-server --watch Data/db.json --port 8000`, it throws an error

```
TypeError [ERR_PARSE_ARGS_UNKNOWN_OPTION]: Unknown option '--watch'. To specify a positional argument starting with a '-', place it at the end of the command after '--', as in '-- "--watch"


PS C:\Users\dewas\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\React tutorial\tuts> npx json-server --port 8000 --watch Data/db.json
node:internal/util/parse_args/parse_args:98
    throw new ERR_PARSE_ARGS_UNKNOWN_OPTION(
          ^

TypeError [ERR_PARSE_ARGS_UNKNOWN_OPTION]: Unknown option '--watch'. To specify a positional argument starting with a '-', place it at the end of the command after '--', as in '-- "--watch"
    at checkOptionUsage (node:internal/util/parse_args/parse_args:98:11)
    at node:internal/util/parse_args/parse_args:360:9
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at parseArgs (node:internal/util/parse_args/parse_args:357:3)
    at file:///C:/Users/dewas/OneDrive/Desktop/Projects/React%20tutorial/node_modules/json-server/lib/bin.js:13:33
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:218:25)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:329:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:28:7)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:113:12) {
  code: 'ERR_PARSE_ARGS_UNKNOWN_OPTION'
}
```

Comment: You need to install the stable version or use a valid command for the version you've installed.

Comment: I need to install new version of json server or node?

Comment: The error is not about your Node version, it's `json-server` that's changed - you're running a command for v0 but using v1. You either need to change the command or the version.

Comment: But the problem is it is not even showing which json server I am using                                                        PS C:\Users\dewas\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\React tutorial\tuts> json-server -v
node:internal/util/parse_args/parse_args:98
    throw new ERR_PARSE_ARGS_UNKNOWN_OPTION(      
          ^

TypeError [ERR_PARSE_ARGS_UNKNOWN_OPTION]: Unknown option '-v'. To specify a positional argument starting with a '-', place it at the end of the command after '--', as in '-- "-v"
    and I have used the npm i json server command too......still problem persists?

Comment: `json-server` doesn't support a `-v` flag, you can see which version is installed with e.g. `npm ls json-server`. I've written a canonical post with the various versions and the error messages people are seeing, to give a more consistent (and easily Google-able) picture: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77787616/3001761

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unexpected errors and warnings when running json-server --watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77787616/unexpected-errors-and-warnings-when-running-json-server-watch)

Comment: Problem solved Thanks for guiding me as I am very new to this........PS C:\Users\dewas\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\React tutorial\tuts> json-server --watch db.json
>>
--watch/-w can be omitted, JSON Server 1+ watches for file changes by default
File db.json not found
PS C:\Users\dewas\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\React tutorial\tuts> json-server Data/db.json
JSON Server started on PORT :3000
Press CTRL-C to stop
Watching Data/db.json...

(˶ᵔ ᵕ ᵔ˶)

Index:
http://localhost:3000/

Static files:
Serving ./public directory if it exists

Endpoints:
http://localhost:3000/blogs

Answer (score 0):

From [json-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server) docs

$ npx json-server db.json --port 8000

Comment: $ : The term '$' is not recognized as the name 
of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable   
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a  
path was included, verify that the path is        
correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ $ npx json-server --watch Data/db.json --port   
8000
+ ~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ($  
   :String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundExc  
   eption

Comment: @DewashishSahu the `$` is the shell prompt, not the start of the command...